# GMP (MPIR) - keep leading zeros when init

Tags: c, gmp

I'm working on a program where we read in a string of ones and zeroes "0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 ..." etc as input.

For part of the program, we need to convert this string to a bit vector/array of bits. Conveniently, mpz_init_set_str offers this functionality in the GMP library (the rest of the program uses GMP to speed up computation).

However, what happens is that the first set of zeroes get ignored until we hit a one because `mpz_init_set_str` discards leading zeroes: https://github.com/alisw/GMP/blob/master/mpz/set_str.c#L103

Is there a function within the GMP library such that mpz_init_set_str does not ignore leading zeroes?

I realize I could modify the GMP library to get around the issue, but I think that would be painful for users to install.

```
while ((bytesRead = fread(buffer, 1, 8192, file)) > 0)
        {
            mpz_init_set_str(res, buffer, 2);
            mpz_export(buff, &result, 1, 1, 0, 0, res);
            for (size_t i = 0; i < result; i++) {
                fputc(buff[i], fptr);
            }
            mpz_clear(res);
        }
```

Comment: Can you add a fake 1 in first position? I don't really understand what you are hoping to do with that number.

Comment: I read large file which contains only 0's and 1's, then I'd like to convert them to ASCII. But due the the task's requirements it is crucial to keep leading zeros

Comment: @MarcGlisse Hmmm...I just tried this but it means I should be able to reverse it after GMP export. Tried something like this: set leading zero char to '1' then did mpz init then export, after all get the first char's int value (which I changed) - 128 and then convert back to unsigned char

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added "fake" 1 and then got that bit and convert back to its old value:

```
unsigned char newCh = (char)((int)buff[0] - 128);
```